# Spring Expression Evaluation (Annotation)

Tags: spring, annotations

I have the following issue:

Using Spring, I would like to propagate the value referenced by the property 'password' to a class variable:

```
 @Value("${password}")
 private String password;
```

That works as long as spring can find the property called 'password'. Since it will not be defined for all different executions, I would like to be able to have a default value assigned when the passwort property is not available.

I found the following example:

```
 @Value("${size_count?:5}")
 private int count;
```

This works. But when I try the same for password (for type String), it will always evaluate to false and return the string 'x' although the password property has been defined.

```
 @Value("${password?:x}")
 private String password;
```

any ideas?

Cheers
chris

Answer (score 1):

Try (I'm guessing, not sure if it makes sense)

```
@Value("${password}?:'x'")
```

Comment: That's the exact thing I would've suggested. +1 for that, whether it's right or not :-)

Comment: Thanks. I came up with that idea as well. If the password was 'bla' then the result of that expression would be:
bla?:'x'

So the expression must be within {}.

Comment: :) haha... what do you think?

Comment: @chr1s - I have to ask. Often people assume something that they haven't tried. Combined with the "wolud" word :)

Comment: fair enough. I actually tried! And that is the result. The 'would' word has been in combination with the if-sentence :)

Comment: @chr1s ok - I'll give it a try in a few hours, have to finish something else now.

Answer (score 1):

`?:` is used in Spring Expression Language, i.e. `#{...}`.

In property placeholders (`${...}`) you need to use `:`:

```
@Value("${password:x}") 
private String password;
```

Comment: +1 for this: because is the correct synax for the property placeholder configurer